# how to start Delayed_Job automatically when the app start ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I start my rails server, I was wondering which is the best way to run this command automatically

```
RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start
```

so delayed_job daemon also starts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and configure your `Procfile` lile:

```
server: rails server
delayed: bundle exec script/delayed_job start
```

Then all you need to do to start everything is:

```
foreman start
```

Comment: Thanks, does forman starts on its own when the rails server starts if I include the gem in Gemfile ? otherwise manually starting foreman start kills the whole purpose :)

Comment: If you add the gem to the `Gemfile`, create a `Procfile` (with the code above) at the root of your application, you don't need to do `rails server` anymore, only `foreman start`. It doesn't really kill the purpose because you still have only one command to run, it's just not the same anymore.

Answer (score 2):

you can look at [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) which has an amazing [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman) to start every service that you want to start when you start your rails server

Comment: Thanks, does forman starts on its own when the rails server starts if I include the gem in Gemfile ? otherwise manually starting foreman start kills the whole purpose :)

Comment: As Tim mentioned, when you use foreman, you should also use it to start your rails server.  No, foreman doesn't start automatically, you need to run `foreman start` to do that.